# My gesturehandler is not working while using expo cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I installed `gesturehandler` but I think it did not install successfully. It gives vulnerabilities issues during import.
I imported it but it was not working. When I do `expo start`, it gives me this error:

[image]
[image]